# Switching two grids in one page on button click

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

Im new in asp.net.. i been working on this since yesterday and theres no luck to figure it out.. why the other grid wont appear on the page since i already put a flag on its code behind.

hope someone can help me on this. thanks.

```
   protected void Edit_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FLAG_hiddenfield.Value == "T")
        {
            BIRPER_EDIT_grid.Visible = true;
            BIRPER_grid.Visible = false;
            Edit_btn.Text = "View";



            BIRPER_grid.DataBind();
            BIRPER_EDIT_grid.DataBind();

            FLAG_hiddenfield.Value = "F";
        }

        if (FLAG_hiddenfield.Value == "F")
        {
            BIRPER_grid.Visible = true;
            BIRPER_EDIT_grid.Visible = false;
            Edit_btn.Text = "Edit";


            BIRPER_grid.DataBind();
            BIRPER_EDIT_grid.DataBind();

            FLAG_hiddenfield.Value = "T";
        }


    }
```

Comment: please check that it is going to other if condition, use breakpoint for that and if it is going to that condition then check that if grid has data to show or not !!

Comment: also check that when you click on edit button then cause of postback the value of FLAG_hiddenfield.Value changed to "T" and it never goes for other condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your conditional logic is wrong here, replace the two `if`s with `if else`:

```
if(FLAG_hiddenfield.Value == "T"){
    ...
}
else if (FLAG_hiddenfield.Value == "F"){
    ...
}
```

Note that if `GridView` contains no data then it is not shown on webpage.